# Emacs + Arduino giving lint errors for native arduino functions like millis()

Tags: emacs, arduino

I am getting red underlines marking errors in a .cpp file I am writing for an Arduino sketch. It is obvious why this is happening, but I want to know if I can fix it.

Is there an Arduino.h file that I can include that will let emacs know that functions like `millis()` actually exist?

Comment: I have checked on my installation; millis() is declared in Arduino.h file, and it is implemented in `../arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c`. One of `Emacs` or `lint` does not know the path to it. Do you have a compilation error ?

Comment: No compilation error. I am just want a functioning ide.